# ajax datatable with rowspan support

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

Do you know any ajax datatable with rowspan attribute support?
I have server-side script for data generation and I want to show this data in table view with grouping some cells in rows.

For example, I want render something like this:

[image: table view example]

[DataTables](http://datatables.net) doesn't support rowspan attribute. It works only with independent rows, right?

Answer (score 0):

While you're absolutely correct that DataTables won't do exactly as your image displayed, there is an option to do a show/hide row detail with any combination of html inside (in your case, it could be a table of columns 3 and 4)

Potentially, this could be a clean way to solve the inevitable UI pattern problem that your example faces: growing quantities of companies, combined with many products will overwhelm the browser (and quickly lower the user experience)

[Here's the example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/row_details.html)

Comment: But I need rowspan attribute support because this table must support row highlighting for user comfort. Ok. Thanks for your answer. Will develop own scripts for this.

Comment: Dmitry, you could still do CSS highlighting of the detail fields inside the "drop down"  Alternatively, you could "zebra stripe" them as well.